# Adjunctions via Universal Arrows: Understanding a Proof.

Tags: category-theory, intuition, self-learning

I've having trouble understanding something in Turi's *Category Theory Lecture Notes* from The University of Edinburgh, which can be found [here](http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/dt/CT/categories.pdf). It's the proof of Theorem 7.1, part (3).

Here's the statement of the theorem:

> Given a functor $U:\mathbf{D}\to\mathbf{C}$, if for every object $A$ of $\mathbf{C}$ there exists a universal arrow $\eta _{A}: A\to UF_{A}$ from $A$ to $U$, then the following holds:
>
> 1. The function $F$ from objects of $\mathbf{C}$ to objects of $\mathbf{D}$ extends, by universality, to a functor $$F:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{D}$$ in the opposite direction to $U$.
> 2. The arrow $\eta _{A}$ is natural in $A$: $$\eta :Id\Rightarrow UF$$.
> 3. For every object $Y$ of $\mathbf{D}$ there is a universal arrow $\varepsilon _{Y}:FUY\to Y$ from $F$ to $Y$ obtained by universality:
>
> [image]
>
> 4. The arrow $\varepsilon _{Y}$ is natural in $Y$: $$\varepsilon : FU\Rightarrow Id.$$

Here's some of the proof so far.

Remember that, by definition of universality, for every $A\in\mathbf{C}$ there is some $F_{A}\in\mathbf{C}$ and some $\eta _{A}:A\to UF_{A}=UFA$ such that for any $f: A\to UY$, there exists a unique $f^{\sharp}:FA\to Y$ *such that* $f=Uf^{\sharp}\circ\eta_{A}$. The proof of part (1) gives us that for any $h:A\to B$ there exists a unique $Fh:= (\eta_{B}\circ h)^{\sharp}: FA\to FB$.

For any $Y\in\mathbf{D}$, universality then gives us a unique $\varepsilon_{Y}:=(id_{UY})^{\sharp}: FUY\to Y$ such that $id_{UY}=U\varepsilon_{Y}\circ\eta_{UY}$. [Think of putting $A=UY$ for just for a moment.]

In order to show that $\varepsilon_{Y}$ is a universal arrow *from $F$ to $Y$*, we need to show that for any $g:FA\to Y$, there exists a unique $g^{\flat }:A\to UY$ such that $g=\varepsilon_{Y}\circ Fg^{\flat }$.

For any such $g$ define $$g^{\flat}:=A\stackrel{\eta_{A}}{\longrightarrow}UFA\stackrel{Ug}{\longrightarrow}UY$$.

I've proven that, indeed, $$g=(g^{\flat})^{\sharp}$$ but **I don't understand why $$(g^{\flat})^{\sharp}=\varepsilon_{Y}\circ Fg^{\flat}$$ follows from the naturality of $\eta$**.

I think I'm nearly there with this overworked diagram

[image]

but I just don't see it yet. I can't prove it to myself. Please help. Is there something really subtle yet easy I've missed?

Thank you in advance.

[NB: The notes are about to introduce adjunctions via universal arrows so I want to play along (i.e. stick to what's given so far).]

Comment: The theorem is on page 34. Also, if you want the code for the diagram, just ask :)

Comment: Plus: if you think that diagram is bad, you should see the one on my whiteboard!

Comment: It might be a good idea to tell us the theorem so we don't have to go rummaging around online to find it.

Comment: That's absolutely fair enough. I was considering whether to include it but decided not to on account of how available the notes are. I'm just having lunch now; I'll type it up soon.

Comment: [In the meantime here's a link to the notes: http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/dt/CT/categories.pdf .]

Comment: There's more editing to come.

Comment: Is that okay now? :)

Comment: I think that's much better for those reading the question. I wish I could help but I'm a bit out of my depth here.

Comment: That's okay, Daniel.

Comment: I'm still stuck. I should not be stuck on this for this long :/

Comment: @Shaun I don't get it: it seems you're trying to prove that the $\eta_A$'s are universal, but isn't that you hypothesis?

Comment: @Giorgio Mossa: That may be but I doubt it. I think that should say $\varepsilon_{Y}$ there. Do you see it? Sorry. It's the existence part of the universality of the $\varepsilon_{Y}$s.

Comment: Ah ok, so it's $\epsilon$'s ok. :)

Comment: I've made a correction. Thanks for kind of pointing that out :)

Comment: @Giorgio Mossa: I could really do with some input, please. Have you got any ideas? I've rearranged the messy diagram a few times and I reckon I'm close. Consider $U(\varepsilon_{Y}\circ Fg^{\flat })$. But what about $\eta_{UY}$?

Comment: Oh - I think I've done it! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the proof follows from a combo of naturality of the $\eta_A$'s and their universal property.

From naturality we get the commutativity of the following diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}A @>\eta_A>> UF(A) \\ @V{g^\flat}VV @V{UF(g^\flat)}VV\\ U(Y) @>{\eta_{U(Y)}}>> UFU(Y)\end{CD}$$
and composing on the left with $U(\epsilon_Y)$ we get that 
$$g^\flat = U(\epsilon_Y)\circ \eta_{U(Y)} \circ g^\flat = U(\epsilon_Y \circ F(g^\flat))\circ \eta_A$$
where the first equality follows the construction of $\epsilon_Y$.

From this equality we end up with the commutative square
$$\begin{CD}A @>\eta_A>> UF(A) \\ @V\eta_AVV @VVU(\epsilon_Y \circ F(g^\flat))V \\ UF(A) @>U(g)>> U(Y)\end{CD}$$ 
and the from the universal property of $\eta_A$ it follows that $g=\epsilon_Y \circ F(g^\flat)$.

Since $g=(g^\flat)^\sharp$ it follows that $(g^\flat)^\sharp = \epsilon_Y \circ F(g^\flat)$.

Comment: The solution I found was only slightly different: I made use of $id_{UY}=U\varepsilon_{Y}\circ\eta_{UY}$ and the uniqueness condition on $(g^{\flat})^{\sharp}$. However, I think yours is better. Thank you!

Comment: @Shaun you're welcome.

Comment: It says I have to wait 18 hours until I can give you the bounty :/