# Adjunctions via Universal Arrows

Tags: category-theory, self-learning

[Adjunctions via Universal Arrows: Understanding a Proof.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554195/adjunctions-via-universal-arrows-understanding-a-proof)

I got stuck here while reading this question.

$g=(g^♭)^♯$

How can I derive this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any morphism $f : A \to UY$, the adjunct $f^\sharp$ is defined to be the *unique* morphism $f^\sharp : FA \to Y$ such that $U(f^\sharp) \circ \eta_A = f$.

If $g: FA \to Y$ then $g^\flat: A \to UY$ is defined to be $Ug \circ \eta_A$.  Then $(g^\flat)^\sharp$ is the *unique* morphism such that $U((g^\flat)^\sharp) \circ \eta_A = g^\flat$. Since $Ug\circ \eta_A = g^\flat$, by uniqueness we have $g = (g^\flat)^\sharp$.

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't know it was so difficult to prove the uniqueness of morphism. As a beginner in category theory, is there any books or papers that I can refer to?

Comment: there's no proof of the uniqueness of any morphism here - you should read it again.  The uniqueness follows from the hypothesis of the theorem in the question you linked (it comes from the notion of a *universal arrow* which is defined in section 3 of the text linked in that question).